# How to set session cookie when saving a document with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, session, mongoose

**NOTE:** The code below uses a module called [client-sessions by Mozilla](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions)

I have a form to register users,  and on form submission a POST is sent to `app.post("/register)` ( in the code below ). If I then go to the homepage route which is `/` I can see a `console.log(user)` which outputs the user info.

This is what I want.

However,

When I register as a new user *I expect the session to be reset*, and when I go to the homepage route for the second time I expect to see the new user info output to the console -  but I don't. Instead I see the first users info. I want to know why the session isn't being reset and replaced with the new user info and/or what I'm not understanding here.

Thank you.

```
app.use(session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: "whatever",
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}))






app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.user === undefined) {
        res.render("index");
    } else {
        User.findOne(req.session.user.email, function(err, user) {

            console.log(user); //__________________This ALWAYS outputs the first user registered even if new users register

        })
        res.render("index");
    }
})


app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
    res.render("register");
})





//_______________________________________________BEGIN registration


app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
    req.session.reset();
    var user = new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.email,
        subscribed: false

    }).save(function(err) {
        req.session.user = user;
        res.redirect("/");
    })
})

//_______________________________________________END registration
```

**ANSWER**

The answer to this is two fold. First the accepted answer below.

Also it makes no sense to store the session inside the save method. Corrected code below

```
app.post("/register", function(req, res) {

    var user = new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        subscribed: false

    })

    req.session.user = user;    // This needed to be outside the save method

    user.save(function(err) {

        res.redirect("/");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with sessions, but with your db query.

Instead of

```
User.findOne(req.session.user.email, function(err, user) {
```

it should be

```
User.findOne({email: req.session.user.email}, function(err, user) {
```

Otherwise, query always returns the first document from users collection.

Comment: When I use your code all I get returned from the console.log(user) is null

Comment: Ensure that `req.session.user.email` exists then. E.g. put `console.log(req.session.user.email)` one line above the db query to check. Actually it is not a good idea to store the whole mongoose document into the session, as it all is going to be encoded into one cookie string by `client-sessions`.

Comment: Its not being created, but I have no idea why. So frustrating. I tried just storing email instead of the entire document, it didn't work either.

Comment: I figured it out...it was two fold. One issue was what you pointed out , the other was the this issue I mentioned in the above answer I added to the question. Thanks